# Method Not Allowed (POST) using DeleteView

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and i using Class based views to add a delete option to my Restaurant List, However when i click the delete button i am getting a blank screen and getting the following error in the console 
"Method Not Allowed (POST):"

Below is my code

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import View
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView, 
CreateView,DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class RestaurantDeleteView(DeleteView):
model = RestaurantLocation
success_url = reverse_lazy('restaurants:list')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from .views import (

     RestaurantListView,
     RestaurantDetailView,
     RestaurantCreateView,
     RestaurantDeleteView,
   )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create/$', RestaurantCreateView.as_view(), name= 'create'),
    url(r'^$',RestaurantListView.as_view(), name= 'list'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',RestaurantDetailView.as_view(),        
          name="detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', RestaurantDeleteView.as_view(), 
     name="restaurant-delete"),
   ]
```

delete.html

```
<form method="post" action="" >{% csrf_token %}
<p>Are you sure you want to delete <strong> {{ obj }}</strong>?</p>
<input type="submit" value="DELETE" />
</form>
```

Comment: Show the full traceback. Are you sure it says POST? For some reason you've set the method to "t" in your form.

Comment: Yea a mistake on my part i corrected it but it still says method not allowed. Edited it to recorrect the mistake

Answer (score 0):

method in your delete.html is currently "t", change to "post" and see if that works.

Comment: that was a mistake on my part, thanks for that heads up, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your form action is pointing to root url that is `/`. 
This route is determined by the `RestaurantListViews` and it is accesed via `GET` method.
In your example, you are trying to access this using `POST`, thus you're getting the error.

To make use of your `RestaurantDeleteView` change the `action` property in your form to point to an existing restaurant, like:

```
<form method="post" action="{your_existing_restaurant_slug}/delete" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
...
```